# How sanitize and store user input, that contains HTML regex pattern in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, security, html-sanitizing

I working on some WordPress plugin that one of its features is ability to store HTML regex pattern, entered by user, to DB and then display it on settings page.

My method is actually work but I wonder if that code is secure enough:

That's the user entered pattern:

```
<div(.+?)class='sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled'(.*?)>(.+?)<\div><\div><\div>
```

That's the way I'm storing HTML pattern in DB:

```
$print_options['custom_exclude_pattern'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['custom_exclude_pattern']),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

That's how it's actually stored in WordPress DB:

```
s:22:"custom_exclude_pattern";s:109:"&lt;div(.+?)class=&quot;sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled&quot;(.*?)&gt;(.+?)&lt;\div&gt;&lt;\div&gt;&lt;\div&gt;";
```

And that's how the output is displayed on settings page:

```
<input type="text" name="custom_exclude_pattern" value="<?php echo str_replace('"',"'",html_entity_decode($print_options['custom_exclude_pattern'])); ?>" size="30" />
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: secure from what exactly?

Comment: If you're talking about SQL injection, then no, you have to use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Dagon from any point that can compromise site security. Xss, SQL injecting etc...

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Thanks Nino, in that specific case I guess WordPress prepares secure SQL query, using `update_options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you are concerned about two separate issues (and possibly unaware of a third one that I will mention in a minute) and looking for one solution for both: **SQL Injection** and **Cross-Site Scripting**. You have to treat each one separately. I implore you to [read this article by Defuse Security](https://defuse.ca/web-application-security.htm).

### How to Prevent SQL Injection

This has been [answered before on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2224584) with respect to PHP applications in general. WordPress's [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) supports prepared statements, so you don't necessarily have to figure out how to work with PDO or MySQLi either. (However, any vulnerabilities in their driver **WILL** affect your plugin. Make sure you read the `$wpdb` documentation thoroughly.

[You should *not* escape the parameters](https://appsec.solutions/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) before passing them to a prepared statement. You'll just end up with munged data.

### Cross-Site Scripting

As of this writing (June 2015), there are two general situations you need to consider:

1. The user should **not** be allowed to submit any HTML, CSS, etc. to this input.
2. The user is allowed to submit some HTML, CSS, etc. to this input, but we don't want them to be able to hack us by doing so.

The first problem is straightforward enough to solve:

```
echo htmlentities($dbresult['field'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

The second problem is a bit tricky. It involves allowing only certain markup while not accidentally allowing other markup that can be leveraged to get Javascript to run in the user's browser. The current gold standard in XSS defense while allowing some HTML is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org).

#### Important!

Whatever your requirements, you should **always apply your XSS defense on output, not before inserting stuff into the database**. Recently, Wordpress core had a [stored cross-site scripting vulnerability](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html) that resulted from the decision to escape before storing rather than to escape before rendering. By supplying a sufficiently long comment, attackers could trigger a MySQL truncation bug on the escaped text, which allowed them to bypass their defense.

### Bonus: PHP Object Injection from `unserialize()`

> That's how it's actually stored in WordPress DB:
>
> `s:22:"custom_exclude_pattern";s:109:"&lt;div(.+?)class=&quot;sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled&quot;(.*?)&gt;(.+?)&lt;\div&gt;&lt;\div&gt;&lt;\div&gt;";`

It looks like you're using `serialize()` when storing this data and, presumably, using `unserialize()` when retrieving it. **Be careful with `unserialize()`**; if you let users have any control over the string, they can [inject PHP objects](https://blog.udemy.com/php-injection) into your code, which can also lead to Remote Code Execution.

Remote Code Execution, for the record, means they can take over your entire website and possibly the server that hosts your blog. If there is any chance that a user can alter this record directly, I highly recommend using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` instead.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Perfect answer! Just wonted to point out that in my code I'm using `htmlentities` before inserting to DB, and `html_entity_decode` on retrieve

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to decode them before inserting into an attribute. Instead, store it naked and encode before displaying on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got the point, if not then correct me: you are trying to dynamically insert a pattern for an input field, based on the same pattern being stored in your db, right?
Well, personally I think patterns are a good help for usability, in that the user knows his input format is not correct without needing to submit and refresh every time. 
The big problem of patterns is, HTML code can be modified client-side. I believe the only safe solution would be to check server-side for the correctness of the input... There is no way a client side procedure can be safer than a server-side one!

Comment: Thanks @Velnias. My question actually is more specific, How do I take user input, that contains some HTML regex pattern, and sainitize it the right way before inserting into DB and after extracting from DB and output as HTML in browser.

Comment: Don't sanitize, use prepared statements. If you're worried about XSS, escape HTML entities on output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are gonna let your user input a regex, you could just do something like prepared statement +  `htmlentities($input, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-I");` to sanitize the input, and then do the opposite, that is `html_entity_decode($dataFromDb, ENT_COMPAT, " UTF-8");`. A must is the prepared statement, all the other ways to work around a malicious input can be combined in lots of different ways!